# Bash IFS causes unexected results with array output

Tags: arrays, bash, curl, echo, ifs

When IFS has its default value and an array is printed without quotes, the interpreted value doesn't have quotes, but when IFS doesn't have a space it it, it does.

Using an echo web server and curl to demonstrate why this makes a difference:

```
bash-5.2$ echo $BASH_VERSION 
+ echo '5.2.21(1)-release'
5.2.21(1)-release
bash-5.2$ declare -a testit=([0]="-H" [1]="foo: bar")
+ testit=(['0']='-H' ['1']='foo: bar')
+ declare -a testit
bash-5.2$ declare -p testit
+ declare -p testit
declare -a testit=([0]="-H" [1]="foo: bar")
bash-5.2$ IFS=$' \t\n'
+ IFS='         
'
bash-5.2$ declare -p IFS
+ declare -p IFS
declare -- IFS=$' \t\n'
bash-5.2$ echo ${testit[@]}
+ echo -H foo: bar
-H foo: bar
bash-5.2$ curl [::1] ${testit[@]}
+ curl '[::1]' -H foo: bar
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [::1]
User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
Accept: */*

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bar
bash-5.2$ echo "${testit[@]}"
+ echo -H 'foo: bar'
-H foo: bar
bash-5.2$ curl [::1] "${testit[@]}"
+ curl '[::1]' -H 'foo: bar'
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [::1]
User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
Accept: */*
foo: bar

bash-5.2$ IFS=$'_\t\n'
+ IFS='_        
'
bash-5.2$ declare -p IFS
+ declare -p IFS
declare -- IFS=$'_\t\n'
bash-5.2$ echo ${testit[@]}
+ echo -H 'foo: bar'
-H foo: bar
bash-5.2$ curl [::1] ${testit[@]}
+ curl '[::1]' -H 'foo: bar'
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [::1]
User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
Accept: */*
foo: bar

bash-5.2$ echo "${testit[@]}"
+ echo -H 'foo: bar'
-H foo: bar
bash-5.2$ curl [::1] "${testit[@]}"
+ curl '[::1]' -H 'foo: bar'
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [::1]
User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
Accept: */*
foo: bar
```

Why does the removal of the space from IFS (regardless of where you put the space, and regardless of whether you replace the space with another character; underscore, for example) cause this different behavior? The only value of IFS on *output* is the first character, and it doesn't matter where the space is to cause the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Don't use POSIX shells like Bash for anything other than trivial job control. Use a modern shell like Elvish or Fish (which don't have an IFS variable and all the problems it causes) or a programming language like Python or Go for this type of thing.

Comment: @KurtisRader I didn't know Elvish, until now... I've read this: [Elvish Shell](https://elv.sh/), then tried (in [tag:bash]): `curl -sL xkcd.com/{1100..1111}/info.0.json |jq -r '[ ( .num|tostring ),.title ]|join(": ")'` then I still don't understand why to reinvent wheel...

Comment: You didn't spend even a second learning how to use Elvish @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub. The point of my recommending using Elvish is that it has native support for JSON. Which means you don't need to use the `jq` command. And your "don't understand why to reinvent the wheel"  comment is also hard to understand. The whole point of my prior comment to use a shell like Elvish is that it avoids the problematic IFS splitting of POSIX shells like Bash.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what the code in your question is intended to show us. In particular I have no idea why there are `curl` commands in it if you're just asking why array contents get printed in different ways. Please [edit] your question to show a test script we can copy/paste to replicate your problem, not just a bunch of separate commands with stderr and stdout output interleaved. Also, don't name variables `test` as that's the name of a command and so obfuscates your code at best.

Comment: “Using an echo web server and curl to demonstrate why this makes a difference:”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IFS` is used to split the result of a parameter expansion, per [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) in the manual:

```
The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, 
and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.

The shell treats each character of $IFS as a delimiter, and splits 
the results of the other expansions into words using these characters 
as field terminators.
```

When `IFS` contains a space, the unquoted expansion `foo: bar` gets split into the two words `foo:` and `bar`. When you remove the space from `IFS` this splitting does not occur, so the debug output displays `'foo: bar'` in quotes to indicate that this is a single word on the command line and not two words like the space might otherwise indicate. You would also get the quotes in the debug output if `IFS` contains a space but you quote the variable expansion to disable word splitting.

```
user@host$ var='foo: bar'
user@host$ set -x
user@host$ echo $var
+ echo foo: bar
foo: bar
user@host$ echo "$var"
+ echo 'foo: bar'
foo: bar
user@host$ declare -p IFS
+ declare -p IFS
declare -- IFS="    
"
```

Comment: Clearly I had a misunderstanding of where/what `IFS` is used for.

Answer (score 1):

IFS only affects arrays when you use `*` as the index, **and** you put the parameter expansion in double quotes:

```bash
$ a=(foo bar baz)
$ IFS=":"
$ printf '%s\n' ${a[@]}
foo
bar
baz
$ printf '%s\n' ${a[*]}
foo
bar
baz
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
foo
bar
baz
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[*]}"
foo:bar:baz
```

Comment: I don't believe this is quite the same thing as what OP is asking about. `IFS` is used to concatenate all the elements into a single word when referenced as `"${a[*]}"` as a special array expansion rule but quoting itself also disables traditional uses of IFS. An unquoted array still undergoes word splitting just like an unquoted variable.

Comment: If your array was `a=( foo bar:baz )` then `printf '%s\n' ${a[@]}` would have different outputs with default IFS vs `IFS=:`.